# How to calculate waiting time in windows phone?

Tags: datetime, windows-phone-8, timespan

I have the entry date and time like 27-06-2013 14:25:01 and exit date and time like 27=06-2013 16:34:34 then how to calculate the spending time or waiting time from the entry time to exit time.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**Now I got a solution from this page.....**

[Please visit here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/458-How-find-difference-between-two-Dates-C-or.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this will help you..

```
int a = (date1 - dt).Hours;
```

date1 and dt ate datetime type

it will give you the difference in hours..